# Highlight Text plugin breaks when using with array string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery Based text highlight plugin, it works for single word highlight but breaks when i pass array, My syntax seems to be correct as the the documentation http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YyAXP/6/

```
//$('#article').highlight("me");
$("#article").highlight(["me","highlight","plugin"]);
```

I need to pass several keywords to this function so that it highlight all of them.

**Solved**:

It seems script had bug which was resolved use the following fiddle with complete script for array based search highlight [script source](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ogyyvvog/2/

Comment: I don't know which version of higlight you used, but when I use the current version from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bartaz/sandbox.js/master/jquery.highlight.js it just works fine

Comment: I think the one i am using is v4, while your example shows v3, Check latest fiddle mentioned in the example

Answer (score 1):

Declaration syntax is correct

```
$("#article").highlight(["me","highlight","plugin"]);
```

You just need to correctly include the plugin in your jsfiddle. Do not include tag script, use instead "External Resources" menu... [check updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YyAXP/9/)

Answer (score 1):

It gets error when running your code

> pat.toUpperCase is not a function

*pat* should be array, maybe you can fix it in this way?

```
return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<pat.length;i++)
        innerHighlight(this, pat[i].toUpperCase());            
}) : this;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f80ocut0/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my highlighting plugin [jQuiteLight](https://github.com/iamwebdesigner/jQuiteLight), that can easily work with both arrays and also regular expressions.

```
// for strings
$(".element").mark("query here");
// for RegExp
$(".element").mark(new RegExp(/query reg[a-zA-Z]+/));
// for array
$(".element").mark(["string query", new RegExp(/query arr[a-z]+/)]);
```

Comment: Does it support multilingual languages like arabic, persian, urdu, hindi

Comment: Tried with chinese and russian, it works fine, but you cant use `useSmartBehavior` option. Please rise issues if you have tested and found bugs.